# Logstash lost messages

Tags: parsing, logging, logstash

I've found that my logstash lost messages. For testing purposes I've added keyword **"MEM"** to Multihub-log, which appears at log file every one minute. I've waited a few minutes without any result.

After that I've deleted *MultihubTST2-log* and *MultihubTST3-log* from my config and only after that I've received zabbix notifications (from logstash output).

Please advise how to resolve this issue, maybe is something wrong in my configuration file.

- Logstash version: 1.5.1
- OS: Windows 2008R2 X64

My config file is below:

```
input {
file {
   path => ["C:\QUIK\Multihub\multihub.log"]
   type => "Multihub-log"
   codec => plain { charset => "UTF-8" }
   start_position => "end"
   stat_interval => 1
   discover_interval => 5
   sincedb_path => "C:\Progra~1\logstash\sincedb\sincedb_multihub"
}
file {
  path => ["C:\QUIK\Multihub_TST2\multihub.log"]
  type => "MultihubTST2-log"
  codec => plain { charset => "UTF-8" }
  start_position => "end"
  stat_interval => 1
  discover_interval => 5
  sincedb_path => "C:\Progra~1\logstash\sincedb\sincedb_multihubtst2"
}
file {
  path => ["C:\QUIK\Multihub_TST3\multihub.log"]
  type => "MultihubTST3-log"
  codec => plain { charset => "UTF-8" }
  start_position => "end"
  stat_interval => 1
  discover_interval => 5
  sincedb_path => "C:\Progra~1\logstash\sincedb\sincedb_multihubtst3"
}
}

filter {
   if [type] == "Multihub-log" and [message] !~ /MEM|exception|Disconnect|Down|Fail|Unavailable|gate/ {
    drop {}
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[@metadata][zabbix_key_mhub]" => "mhub.prod1" }
}
if [type] == "MultihubTST2-log" and [message] !~ /MEM|exception|Disconnect|Down|Fail|Unavailable|gate/ {
    drop {}
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[@metadata][zabbix_key_tst2]" => "mhub.tst2" }
}
if [type] == "MultihubTST3-log" and [message] !~ /MEM|exception|Disconnect|Down|Fail|Unavailable|gate/ {
    drop {}
    }
    mutate {
        add_field => { "[@metadata][zabbix_key_tst3]" => "mhub.tst3" }
}
}
output {

if [type] == "Multihub-log" {
zabbix {
    zabbix_host => "host"
    zabbix_key => "[@metadata][zabbix_key_mhub]"
    zabbix_server_host => "10.1.110.71"
    zabbix_value => "message"
}
}
if [type] == "MultihubTST2-log" {
zabbix {
    zabbix_host => "host"
    zabbix_key => "[@metadata][zabbix_key_tst2]"
    zabbix_server_host => "10.1.110.71"
    zabbix_value => "message"
}
}
if [type] == "MultihubTST3-log" {
zabbix {
    zabbix_host => "host"
    zabbix_key => "[@metadata][zabbix_key_tst3]"
    zabbix_server_host => "10.1.110.71"
    zabbix_value => "message"
}
}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: From what I can see, your config is a mess.  The `mutate`s are not in the `if` blocks.

Comment: Also, why not have each conditional set the key in same meta variable, then you could have one output stanza.